# Extract numerical percentage from string containing multiple numbers

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to extract a numerical percentage in a string. Here are some cases:

- input: "Bank ABC 123% CDE" -> output: 123.00 (as a float)
- input: "Some random bank IPCA + 12,34%" -> output: 12.34
- input: "Bank1 2,3%" -> output: 2.3

Commas are used solely as separators and there's only one percentage for each string, so the following strings will never occur:

- invalid input: "Bank ABC, 123%"
- invalid input: "Bank ABC 123% and 12,34%"

Currently, I'm using the following script in Python

```
def extract_percentage(x: str) -> float:
   float((re.sub(r'[^\d,]', '', x)).replace(',','.'))
```

It works for the first two examples above, but for the third, the output is 12.3

How should I do it? Preferably, using Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex removes spaces, as well as everything else. I think that to find something using regex, the best way is to search for it, using the `re` library.

We will start by looking for all strings ending with `%`: `'.*%'`.
For `Bank ABC 123% CDE` this will return `Bank ABC 123% CDE` which, contains space and non-digits.

To improve on that, let's look for numbers with 1 comma or dot at most: `\d*[,.]?\d*%`, this will return `123%` for your input

To wrap things up, let's replace the comma with a dot

```
import re

str = 'Bank1 2,3%'
arr = [x.replace(',','.') for x in re.findall('\d*[,.]?\d*%',str)]
print(arr)
>>> ['2.3%']
```

Note that the answer is an array of all matches

If you want to get the number out, you can now just do:

```
if len(arr)>0:
  number_without_percent_sign = arr[0][:-1]
  print(float(number_without_percent_sign))
>>> 2.3
```

Comment: thanks, that helps a lot. I just added another replace method to get rid of the "%" and then converted the output to float, it works perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear! You might want to read about regex lookahead. Using them, you could have made the regex output a string without the % sign to begin with

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Shahar Bental's answer above, I got another solution that relies less on regex and uses the split method from python. Not sure if it's better though.

I added the following to my previous script:

```
words = x.split(' ')
for word in words:
  if '%' in word:
    return float((re.sub(r'[^\d,]', '', word)).replace(',','.'))
```

Comment: I don't think this solution is right, as `Bank1 2,3%` returns 12.3. As far as I understand, you don't just want the digits and commans, you want them to be right before a percent sign and together

Comment: it actually returns 2.3, as intended. The `if` statement "filters" the 1 from Bank1.